# HTML5 Canvas color differentiation

Tags: html, css, webkit

I'm trying to draw a popup using HTML5 canvas.
The popup is composed of a canvas that draws an arrow and a div below:

[image: HTML5 Canvas color difference]

As you can clearly see, the color of the arrow is darker than the div's background-color.
The code is injected into every tab of the browser and the popup is shown upon selection of text.

Here's the drawing code:

```
    var ctx = $('#popupCanvas')[0].getContext("2d");
    ctx.moveTo(10, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(0, 10);
    ctx.lineTo(20, 10);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(50,50,50,0.9)";
    ctx.fill();
```

and the CSS of the div is :

```
#popupMenu
{
    line-height: 0px;
    display:block;
    background-color:rgba(50,50,50,0.9);
    color:#ddd;      
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #555;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    font-family: Century Gothic, sans-serif;    
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size:0px;
    padding:5px;
    width:345px;   
}
```

As you can see, the colors are the same and yet they are rendered differently.
What am I doing wrong?
Why are there any differences? I'm using Webkit under chrome 15.

**Edit1**

I forgot to mention, the popup is running as **injected javascript\css**.

Adding the HTML source code:

```
 <div id='popupContainer'>
     <canvas id='popupCanvas' width='20' height='10'/>
     <div id='popupMenu'>
     </div>
 </div>
```

and the full CSS:

```
#popupCanvas
{
    position:relative;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}


#popupContainer
{
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 999999;            
    direction:ltr;
    text-align:center;
}

#popupMenu
{
    line-height: 0px;
    display:block;
    background-color:rgba(50,50,50,0.9);
    color:#ddd;      
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #555;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    font-family: Century Gothic, sans-serif;    
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size:0px;
    padding:5px;
    width:345px;   
}
```

**Edit2**

Here's my entire code upon user selection :

```
this.onTextSelected = function (selText) {
        selectedText = selText;

        // check if we have value
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        var node = document.elementFromPoint(currentMousePos.x, currentMousePos.y);
        if (node.value) {
            rect = getTextBoundingRect(node, $(node).caret().start, $(node).caret().end);
        }
        else
            rect = selection.getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect();

        var bottom = rect.bottom + document.body.scrollTop;
        var left = rect.left + document.body.scrollLeft

        $("#popupContainer").css('top', bottom);

        // Div exceeds left side
        if (left - $("#popupContainer").outerWidth() / 2 < 0) {
            $("#popupContainer").css('left', left);
            // TODO: set the arrow to be left
        }

        // Div exceeds right side   
        else if (left + $("#popupContainer").outerWidth() / 2 > $(window).width()) {
            $("#popupContainer").css('left', left + rect.width - $("#popupContainer").outerWidth());
            // TODO: set the arrow to be right
        }

        else {
            $("#popupContainer").css('left', left + rect.width / 2 - $("#popupContainer").outerWidth() / 2);
        }


        $("#popupContainer").show();      

        var ctx = $('#popupCanvas')[0].getContext("2d");
        ctx.moveTo(10, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(0, 10);
        ctx.lineTo(20, 10);
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(50,50,50,0.9)";
        ctx.fill();
};
```

Comment: I'm afraid the image is broken

Comment: Are you sure? it works here, I forced refresh so I'm sure it doesn't show from the cache.

Comment: No, you're right, it's the filter at work!

Comment: Could you share the JavaScript that injects the popup?

Comment: chrome does the injection all I do is "$("body").append(contentDiv);" and that's how I add my div.

Comment: Ok I have produced a fiddle that injects the divs: http://jsfiddle.net/thebeebs/tGzna/22/ but it dosen't reproduce your issue.

Comment: Do you have a link to the live page where the issue is happening?

Comment: it happens on any page, Wikipedia for example, I've edited my post to show what I do when I detect user text selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest trying to define it in something other than rgba as a potential fix, although it is quite strange.

On another point, i'd consider using a pseudo element (see [here](http://css-tricks.com/9516-pseudo-element-roundup/) for a great article) for the arrow, it seems a bit unnecessary to use a whole canvas element for such a detail. Whilst support might not be fantastic/consistent, neither is that for canvas so I'd say it's likely a good swap.

Answer (score 0):

I'd believe this is because pop-up background shines through canvas (which has alpha 0.9). On the othe hand, pop-up itself is drawn on light background.

Try modify alpha values to see if this is the cause of the problem.

Comment: it happens even if they are far away from each other

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce this issue. Can you provide full code?

I added a fiddle below with a slighlty larger triangle and used un-vendor prefixed versions of border-radius and box shadow so that it works across IE9, Opera and Mozilla as well as webkit browser.

I also added a -5px margin to the bottom div to cause an overlap.

http://jsfiddle.net/thebeebs/tGzna/2/

The triangle colour looks fine across All major browsers to me. All I can think is that the CSS you are using in the picture differs from the CSS you have added in the question (which is possible since there is a black background to the div in your image), somthing on the page in which the code is embeded is effecting the color or there is something undernearth the arrow that is effecting the 0.9 alpha.

I also added something in the background to see if this effected Canvas elements and Div's with Alpha backgrounds differently... but it didn't seem to.

Comment: The black rectangle was just for censorship but you're right, I double checked it and it does works fine on jsfiddle, however, I forgot to mention my code is injected into every tab and probably that's the cause of the problem, I've edited my post and copied the full code.

Comment: BTW, even in the fiddle there's a very slight color difference, looking at the color with Paint's color picker, the arrow is (70,70,70) while the div is (69,69,69)

Comment: Just checked the two colours in IE9 with IE9 developer tools using colour picker. It suggests they are the same 70,70,70 so I tried it in paint... It's the same. But then tried it in Chrome and checked with paint and you are right Chrome gets the colors wrong. I guess this is an issue with their implimentation.

Comment: Mozilla gets it right, (70,70,70). Opera shows (71,71,71) for both elements which is slightly different, but at least it's consistent across their canvas and div.